# Hyperledger Fabric Error with the eventhub : UNIMPLEMENTED: unknown service protos.Deliver

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am using Hyperledger Fabric fabcar " https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/master" example with Angular 6 + NodeJs + Blockchain + CouchDB with some modification.

I am trying to perform CRUD operation with this architecture. GET operation I am doing successfully but while doing POST operation(Changing Ownership or adding some data to the ledger) getting error.

Error:

`gtpl@gtpl-ThinkPad-T430s:~/Music/fabcar/fabcar$ node server.js 
running on port8000
Chnaging the car owner  { Key: 'CAR0', owner: 'Pampa' }
Store path:/home/gtpl/Music/fabcar/fabcar/hfc-key-store
Successfully loaded user1 from persistence
Assigning transaction_id:  07fb8c531615c4c5bd4668ecf5cb99c3135679eabf98a1d9c97d9ed0e8e56470
Transaction proposal was good
Successfully sent Proposal and received ProposalResponse: Status - 200, message - "OK"
Failed to invoke successfully :: Error: There was a problem with the eventhub ::Error: 12 UNIMPLEMENTED: unknown service protos.Deliver"`

My controller.js file is like this..

`
    router.post('/changeOwner',function(req, res){

```
var key = req.body.Key;
var owner = req.body.owner;

var fabric_client = new Fabric_Client();

var channel = fabric_client.newChannel('mychannel');
var peer = fabric_client.newPeer('grpc://localhost:7051');
channel.addPeer(peer);
var order = fabric_client.newOrderer('grpc://localhost:7050')
channel.addOrderer(order);

var member_user = null;
var store_path = path.join(os.homedir(), './Music/fabcar/fabcar/hfc-key-store');
console.log('Store path:'+store_path);
var tx_id = null;

Fabric_Client.newDefaultKeyValueStore({ path: store_path
}).then((state_store) => {
    fabric_client.setStateStore(state_store);
    var crypto_suite = Fabric_Client.newCryptoSuite();
    var crypto_store = Fabric_Client.newCryptoKeyStore({path: store_path});
    crypto_suite.setCryptoKeyStore(crypto_store);
    fabric_client.setCryptoSuite(crypto_suite);
    return fabric_client.getUserContext('user1', true);
}).then((user_from_store) => {
    if (user_from_store && user_from_store.isEnrolled()) {
        console.log('Successfully loaded user1 from persistence');
        member_user = user_from_store;
    } else {
        throw new Error('Failed to get user1.... run registerUser.js');
    }
    tx_id = fabric_client.newTransactionID();
    console.log("Assigning transaction_id: ", tx_id._transaction_id);
    var request = {
        chaincodeId: 'fabcar',
        fcn: 'changeCarOwner',
        args: [key,owner],
        chainId: 'mychannel',
        txId: tx_id
    };

    return channel.sendTransactionProposal(request);
}).then((results) => {
    var proposalResponses = results[0];
    var proposal = results[1];
    let isProposalGood = false;
    if (proposalResponses && proposalResponses[0].response &&
        proposalResponses[0].response.status === 200) {
            isProposalGood = true;
            console.log('Transaction proposal was good');
        } else {
            console.error('Transaction proposal was bad');
        }
    if (isProposalGood) {
        console.log(util.format(
            'Successfully sent Proposal and received ProposalResponse: Status - %s, message - "%s"',
            proposalResponses[0].response.status, proposalResponses[0].response.message));

        var request = {
            proposalResponses: proposalResponses,
            proposal: proposal
        };

        var transaction_id_string = tx_id.getTransactionID(); 

        var sendPromise = channel.sendTransaction(request);
        promises.push(sendPromise); 

        let event_hub = channel.newChannelEventHub('localhost:7051');
        let txPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            let handle = setTimeout(() => {
                event_hub.disconnect();
                resolve({event_status : 'TIMEOUT'}); 
            }, 3000);
            event_hub.connect();
            event_hub.registerTxEvent(transaction_id_string, (tx, code) => {
                clearTimeout(handle);
                event_hub.unregisterTxEvent(transaction_id_string);
                event_hub.disconnect();

                var return_status = {event_status : code, tx_id : transaction_id_string};
                if (code !== 'VALID') {
                    console.error('The transaction was invalid, code = ' + code);
                    resolve(return_status); // we could use reject(new Error('Problem with the tranaction, event status ::'+code));
                } else {
                    console.log('The transaction has been committed on peer ' + event_hub.getPeerAddr());
                    resolve(return_status);
                }
            }, (err) => {
                reject(new Error('There was a problem with the eventhub ::'+err));
            });
        });
        promises.push(txPromise);

        return Promise.all(promises);
    } else {
        console.error('Failed to send Proposal or receive valid response. Response null or status is not 200. exiting...');
        res.send("Error: no car found");
    }
}).then((results) => {
    console.log('Send transaction promise and event listener promise have completed');
    if (results && results[0] && results[0].status === 'SUCCESS') {
        console.log('Successfully sent transaction to the orderer.');
        res.json(tx_id.getTransactionID())
    } else {
        console.error('Failed to order the transaction. Error code: ' + response.status);
        res.send("Error: no tuna catch found");
    }

    if(results && results[1] && results[1].event_status === 'VALID') {
        console.log('Successfully committed the change to the ledger by the peer');
        res.json(tx_id.getTransactionID())
    } else {
        console.log('Transaction failed to be committed to the ledger due to ::'+results[1].event_status);
    }
}).catch((err) => {
    console.error('Failed to invoke successfully :: ' + err);
    res.send("Error: no car found");
});
```

})`

Not able to figured out what I am missing.
Need clarity on this.

Comment: what fabric version are you using?

Comment: version 1.1.0

I checked the version with this command 

**peer version**

got output like this =>

`peer:
 Version: 1.1.0-preview
 Go version: go1.9
 OS/Arch: linux/amd64
 Experimental features: false
 Chaincode:
  Base Image Version: 0.4.2
  Base Docker Namespace: hyperledger
  Base Docker Label: org.hyperledger.fabric
  Docker Namespace: hyperledger
`

Answer (score 0):

There are different versions of the samples which are updated regularly to reflect updates in Fabric versions.  You cannot always mix and match versions.  Also note that you are very down-level on Fabric ... Fabric just releases version 1.4.0.

I'd suggest you start with https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/install.html to get the latest versions of Fabric and fabric-samples.

`curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hyperledger/fabric/master/scripts/bootstrap.sh | bash -s 1.4.0` will download version 1.4 of both.